# I need help creating multiple arrays for three customers using a code I have created for a finch robot, any suggestions?

Tags: java

//Below is the code I have as the framework and this works, but I now ran into a problem because I need to rework it to use multiple arrays for three customers and I am new to arrays so I am having trouble. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
package Code.simpleInput;
import edu.cmu.ri.createlab.terk.robot.finch.Finch;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Finch {
   private static Scanner sc;

   public static void main(final String[] args)
      {
      // Instantiating the Finch object
      Finch myFinch = new Finch();

      sc = new Scanner(System.in);

      // Providing instructions to the user
      System.out.println("What is your name? ");
      String name = sc.next(); 

      System.out.println("What red value would you like my beak to be?" );
      int red = sc.nextInt();

      System.out.println("What green value would you like my beak to be?" );
      int green = sc.nextInt();

      System.out.println("What blue value would you like my beak to be?" );
      int blue = sc.nextInt();



      System.out.println("What is the amount of your bill? ");
      float bill = sc.nextFloat();

      System.out.println(name + ", your bill amount is "+ bill);


        float taxAmount = (float) (0.0675 * bill);
        float totalWithTax = bill + taxAmount;
        float tipAmount = (float) (totalWithTax * 0.20);
        float grandTotal = totalWithTax + tipAmount;

        //Display it back to the user
        //System.out.println("meal: $" + charge);
        System.out.println("tax: $" + taxAmount);
        System.out.println("meal + tax: $" + totalWithTax);
        System.out.println("total cost(tip included): $" + grandTotal);

        myFinch.setWheelVelocities(255, 255, 1000);
        myFinch.setLED(red,green,blue,1000);
        //myFinch.playClip("filepath_goes_here");
        myFinch.saySomething("Your grandTotal is " + grandTotal);
        myFinch.setWheelVelocities(-255, -255, 1000);

        myFinch.quit();
      System.exit(0);
      }
   }
```

Comment: create a customer's `object` instead

Comment: Please reformulate the title of this post to make represent the question you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey what exactly are you trying to do though? Are you trying to save the same data 3 times for a different customer each? In that case, you could probably make a class that implements all of the above methods and then you could make new objects in accordance with the customers, and save those objects in an array or arraylist. I don't know if that helps, but hopefully!

Comment: I actually only need to save the data including the calculations for the grand total for 3 different customers, not any of the information about asking the name or any of that. I have just never used arrays before because I am just beginning programming so I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Well I think making an object would still be much easier, because all the data relevant to one customer is saved in the same place, and you can make an unlimited amount of objects very easily, but anyway, make an ArrayList (I would recommend that because it grows and shrinks as needed if you ever have more costumers) so do:

    ArrayList<YourObject> array = new ArrayList<YourObject>(); 

heres more info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html